# Hash symbol on a teletype

Tags: terminal, tty, special-characters

My issue is a bit unusual, so I want to provide a short background. I was looking at old winners of the International Obfucated C Code Contest, and came across an entry written for the PDP-11 (the entry is [here](http://www.ioccc.org/1984/mullender.c), for those interested). So, I searched for an emulator, which I found at http://simh.trailing-edge.com/, and booted it with UNIX v7 (from the same site). Again, for those interested, I found instructions on booting it at http://wandel.ca/homepage/unixdemo.html.

With that background in mind, here is my actual issue. As I was typing the program into ed, it was being funny about hash characters. They wouldn't actually save in the file. After a lot of research, I discovered it was emulating a physical teletypewriter (!), and since you couldn't backspace a character printed on paper, a hash meant "ignore the previous character".

So my question is this: How do I actually type a hash character?

Comment: Probably backslash shift 3.  Or Ctrl-V, shift 3.

Comment: @Mikel Ah, backslash shift-3 did it (Ctl-V shift-3 didn't, just for the record). Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On very old systems, <kbd>#</kbd> would delete the previous character, and <kbd>@</kbd> would kill the whole line.

To type a literal <kbd>#</kbd> or <kbd>@</kbd>, you need to type a backslash first, to escape it, e.g. <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>#</kbd> = <kbd>#</kbd>.

These days, the same functionality is provided by the terminal's `lnext` setting, which defaults to <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>.

See also:

- [PDP-11 Simulator](http://www.jbox.dk/sanos/pdp11.htm)
- [stty lnext](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stty)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that V7 supports `stty erase`, but if it does, use that to change erase character to something sane.