# # and @ special characters not working in my unix terminal

Tags: special-characters

I want to see the functioning of # and @ in unix terminal but my terminal isnt able to use them and it just treats them as normal characters. Is there any online compiler where i can see their working. I have already tried some online compilers:  http://www.freelinuxconsole.info/terminal/, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/powershell_terminal_online.php but nothing works here too. Please help.

Comment: Your question is bad elaborared, and I can't understand what's your problem. And please, add an example.

Comment: I want to see the working of # character which functions as backspace and @ which functions as line clear in my terminal but my terminal doesnt detect them as special character. I want to know if there is any way to verify their working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hash symbol on a teletype](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57828/hash-symbol-on-a-teletype)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you been reading some old book on Unix? These characters were used back in the old days of paper terminals, say some 35+ years ago. If you want to use them, you'll have to reconfigure the erase and kill characters with the `stty` command:

```
stty erase \#
stty kill @
```

Comment: Yes i am reading UPE by kernighan and pike and Thanks(as my upvote cant be seen )

Comment: @AyushN if this answer works for you please remember to accept it with the tickmark on its left-hand side.

Comment: Great answer. I didn't couldn't figure out what the question was about!